# Does Wilson Fisk discover that Matt Murdock is Daredevil?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil, daredevil-2015

In netflix' *Marvel's Daredevil* season 2, Wilson Fisk is seen eating steak in his cell. Upon drinking coffee, he again feels a bruise on his lip, inflicted by Matt Murdock which he met earlier. He then calls one of his henchmen, telling him to re-evaluate Matt Murdock's file.

Does Fisk figure out that Murdock is Daredevil, and if so, how? Does he conclude this purely based on the punch Matt threw at his lip?

Comment: If anyone wants to know, [here's the scene at steak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ydnfk-RV8w).

Comment: Also, it's probably wine guys, not coffee, how could I be so foolish.

Comment: Well, hopefully he didn't recognize Matt's chin from all the time he's spent staring at Daredevil's face.

Comment: I think if Fisk ever figured it out he'd have gone after Murdock out of costume, or targeted Foggy or Karen, but that's just me.

Comment: Now that Season 3 has been released, hopefully someone can answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Fisk knows.

While he might have suspected it in the season 2 (although he had no real reasons for that - Matt let Fisk to beat him up in prison), in the season 3 he gets proofs:

**1. He sees Matt fighting in the prison during riot**

Matt goes to prison where Fisk used to be imprisoned to get some information about rival organisations. Fisk bribes some guards and prisoners to start a riot in attempt to kill Murdock - later on we can see Fisk watching the footage from the camera.

[image: Fisk watching the footage from the camera]

**2. In the season finale:**

> First Fisk tells Matt that he will tell everyone about his secret: 
> [image: Fisk tells Matt that he will tell everyone about his secret] 
> Then Matt shows him his face: 
> [image: Matt shows him his face]

Comment: Haha. I was coming here right now to answer the question. You beat me by a few hours. +1. In addition, there is a scene in Season 3 between Karen and Fisk where Karen let slip that Matt is Daredevil (episode 6 I believe).

Comment: Also, I don't believe that Fisk understood about Matt's secret identity in Season 2. I think this scene meant that Fisk understood that Matt (and Foggie) was serious business and there was more to him than a low-tier lawyer from Hell's Kitchen that he could easily eliminate. This scene probably set in motion all the events of the Season 3.

Comment: @Taladris  Did Karen say that Matt is the DD? I thought she only admitted to killing Fisk's friend in season 1. and yes, I agree that in season 2 Fisk didn't know - Matt visited him in prison and Fisk beat him up with Matt not trying to resist it, to avoid blowing his cover.